# Memory leaks problems using valgrind even after fclose

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm having problems with valgrind,the problem is in this function where I have memory leaks apparently.

```
void lectureFichier(const char * nomFichier, message ** tete){

      message * test=creationCellule();

        FILE * fp = fopen(nomFichier, "r");

        if(!fp)
        {

                perror("fopen failed\n");
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }


        while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ",&(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))==2)
        {


               if(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ",&(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))!=2)
               {
                        fprintf(stderr,"fscanf of first two\n");
                        free(test);

                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

               }

                fgets(test->text,100,fp);
                insertion(tete,test);
                test=creationCellule();

        }
        fclose(fp);
     }
```

Take a look at valgrind result:

[image]

I can't find the problem. Do you have any suggestion?

HERE'S THE WHOLE CODE THAT CONTAINS THE FONCTION ABOVE ,WHEN I USE VALGRIND WITH THIS CODE IT GIVES THE RESULT AS SHOWN IN THE PICTURE ABOVE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "tp1.h"

message * creationCellule(){

    message * cellule=NULL;
    free(cellule);
    cellule=malloc(sizeof(message));
    if(!cellule)
    {
            perror("malloc failes\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


        cellule -> dateDeb = 0;
        cellule -> dateFin = 0;
        cellule -> suivant = NULL;
        memset(cellule->text, '\0', TAILLE_MAX);




    return cellule;
}

/*bejme recherche per date de deb se eshte trie nga date deb*/
message * recherche(message * tete, int date){


    message ** prec = tete;
    message * cour = *tete;

    while( cour != NULL && cour -> dateDeb < date){

        prec = &(cour -> suivant);
        cour = cour -> suivant;

    }

    return prec;

}

/*la prochaine fois il faut venir avec un makefile*/
void insertion(message ** tete, message * cellule){

    (void)tete;
    (void)cellule;

    message ** prec;


    if(cellule != NULL){
            prec = recherche(tete, cellule -> dateDeb);
            cellule -> suivant = *prec;
            *prec = cellule;
    }


} 


/*duhet te lexojme fichier ne fillim dhe kete fichier do e krijojme ne vete*/
void lectureFichier(const char * nomFichier, message ** tete){



    message * test=creationCellule();

        FILE * fp = fopen(nomFichier, "r");



        if(!fp)
        {

                perror("fopen failed\n");
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }


        while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ",&(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))==2)
        {


               if(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ",&(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))!=2)
               {
                        fprintf(stderr,"fscanf of first two\n");
                        free(test);

                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

               }

                fgets(test->text,100,fp);
                insertion(tete,test);
                test=creationCellule();

        }

                fclose(fp);


     }  




void affichageListe(message ** tete)
{


    if(tete)
    {
        message * tmp = *tete;
        while( tmp )
        {
                //printf("jam ktu\n");
                    printf("DateDeb = %d \n", tmp -> dateDeb);
            printf("DateFin = %d \n", tmp -> dateFin);
            printf("Text = %s \n", tmp -> text);
            tmp = tmp -> suivant;
        }
    }
}



void suppression(message**tete,int valeur,int dateDeb)
{
        message **prec;

        prec=recherche(tete,dateDeb);

        if((*prec)!=NULL && (*prec)->dateFin==valeur)
        {

                (*prec)=(*prec)->suivant;
        }

}

//EXERCICE 3

void supprimeObsoletes(message **tete)
{

        message *pt=*tete;
        time_t temps;
        struct tm *date;
        int intNum;
        temps=time(NULL);
        date=localtime(&temps);

        char buffer[9];
        if((date->tm_mon)<10){
                sprintf(buffer,"%d0%d%d",date->tm_year + 1900,date->tm_mon +1,date->tm_mday);
        }
        else{
                sprintf(buffer,"%d%d%d",date->tm_year + 1900,date->tm_mon +1,date->tm_mday);
        }

        intNum=atoi(buffer);

        while(pt!=NULL)
        {


                if((pt->dateFin)<intNum)
                {

                     printf("KTU HYB %s\n",pt->text);
                        suppression(tete,pt->dateFin,pt->dateDeb);


                }


                pt=pt->suivant;
         }

}


void changeDate(int dateChange, int dateInit,message **tete)
{


        message *point=*tete;
        //printf("Kjo eshte tete %p:\n",(*point));

        while(point!=NULL)
        {

                if((point->dateDeb)==dateInit)
                {                

                        printf("%d\n",point->dateDeb);
                        printf("%s\n",point->text);

                        point->dateDeb=dateChange;


                }

                point=point->suivant;
        }

}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

        const char * name=argv[1];
        message * pointeur = NULL;
    //message ** tete = &pointeur;
        int dateInit=19973012;
        int dateChange=20003008;
        lectureFichier(name, &pointeur);
        supprimeObsoletes(&pointeur);
        affichageListe(&pointeur);

        while(pointeur)
        {


                message *current=pointeur;
                pointeur=pointeur->suivant;
                free(current);


        }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: did you forget to `fclose` the file?

Comment: @Serge no i have added it at it shows still the same problem

Comment: then ignore it. there are internal libc buffers which are not supposed to be freed.

Comment: @Serge take a look at the whole code please

Comment: your valgrind report points to the internal fopen buffer. nothing else is there. So, it looks like there are no leaks in the program itself.

Comment: Yeah, ignore that. It's not even a memory leak. Running valgrind with the option to show reachable but not freed memory at exit is usually full of false positives like that.

Comment: The `test` seems to be overwritten in the last part of your program if the preceding "if" statement was false.
`

Comment: @Serge so what do I do to fix it? I just added the whole code rn

Comment: @doug in which function?

Comment: Not sure. Your code has been substantially edited. Was referring to the original post. Looks like Mirko caught it.

Answer (score 2):

Your valgrind log shows "fscanf of first two" as part of the program output.  That part happens when the `fscanf` call fails inside of the loop.  You call `exit` but don't close the file.  You need to close the file first:

```
           if(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ",&(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))!=2)
           {
                    fprintf(stderr,"fscanf of first two\n");
                    fclose(fp);
                    free(test);

                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

           }
```

Comment: `exit()` closes open stdio file streams.

Comment: @Shawn what other can I use insted of exit() because I'm not allowed to use that, but if i remove it I get errors from valgrind?

Comment: @dbush thank you soo so so much!! I have a question, how comes that fscanf fails and I enter inside the if?

Comment: @MimozaQati That depends on what your data looks like.  You call it twice in a row, once at the top of the loop and once in the `if` with the former getting discarded.  You probably don't want that inside `fscanf`, so if that's the case then go with Mirko's answer.

Comment: @MimozaQati "Still reachable" memory is not an error.

Comment: @Shawn The problem is not that the stream isn't closed but that the thing the `FILE*` points to isn't deallocated when `valgrind` looks at memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
void lectureFichier(const char * nomFichier, message ** tete)
{
    message * test=creationCellule();

    FILE * fp = fopen(nomFichier, "r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("fopen failed\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ", &(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))==2)
    {
//        Here you are reading again. That's not what you want.
//        if(fscanf(fp,"%d %d ",&(test->dateDeb), &(test->dateFin))!=2)
//        {
//            fprintf(stderr,"fscanf of first two\n");
//            free(test);
//            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//        }
        fgets(test->text,100,fp);
        insertion(tete,test);
        test=creationCellule();
    }
    // Here you can free the last test, because it is not used
    free(test);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is memory leaks then you should use free(fp) for dyamically allocated pointers.